# How to get last quarter in Bash Script

Tags: bash, scripting, date

I have a script that gets the proper quarter but I need to get the (quarter - 1)

```
quarter=$(($(($((10#$(date -d $year$month$day +%m))) - 1)) / 3 + 1))
```

Currently this returns 3, I need it to return 2. I cant figure it out.

Quarter as in quarter of year. 4 quarters in a year.

This runs properly but I need to subtract 1 from the result.

Answered:

```
num=1
quarter=$((quarter-num))
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. What do you mean by quarter? Of the hour? Of the year? What exactly are you trying to do? What is the value of `$year$month$day`?

Comment: Given the number of the month, he wants the related quarter number of the year jan-march = 1 apr-jun= 2 jul-sept=3 oct-nov=4 but want to start from 0 i guess.

Comment: To substract 1, just drop the +1, but for a Jan-Mar date, do you want it to return 0 or 4?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
last_quarter=$(($(date -d "$year$month$day" +'(%-m+8)/3%4+1')))
```

For 2015-02-23, it would return 4 (the 4th quarter of 2014), and for 2015-09-18, 2.